# Android studio error "cannot resolve method"

Tags: java, android, xml

I am facing a problem in the Java code of my application

```
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) 
        {
            Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
            message.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            messages.add(message);
            displayMessages(messages);
        }
```

Error thrown :  `"cannot resolve method"`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing some things try the following code:

```
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
    Post newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
    System.out.println("Author: " + newPost.author);
    System.out.println("Title: " + newPost.title);
    System.out.println("Previous Post ID: " + prevChildKey);
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

  @Override
  public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

  @Override
  public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, all I need to do was.

File 
- Invalidate Cache / Restart

Comment: Describe something about your answer, refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer